# Wheel of Fortune fetching draw results from server?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I made a Wheel of Fortune using d3.js by referencing other tutorials online. The Wheel works fine, but I'm stuck on obtaining spin results from server.

The spinning code is as follow:

```
vis.transition()
  .duration(3000)
  .attrTween("transform", rotTween)
  .each("end", function(){
    //mark prize as seen
    d3.select(".slice:nth-child(" + (picked + 1) + ") path")
      .attr("fill", "#111");

    //populate prize
    d3.select("#prize h1")
      .text(data[picked].prize);
    oldrotation = rotation;
});
```

Full source code is available from [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/ezt30xh9/). How can I obtain results from server? The sample response from server is as follow:

```
{"hit": 1}
```

which is a JSON telling which arc to hit.

Comment: Your question needs more context. Are you asking how to call a server from the browser and act based on the result? Are you trying to set the `picked` variable in the `spin` function based on a server result?

Comment: Yes. When user clicked "Spin", the page should request server to obtain `picked` variable.

Comment: Ok. Look at the docs for [d3.xhr](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_xhr). You should be able to figure it out from there.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
var totalNoOfObjects = 100
var picked = 1;  // should be the server response from 0 to 99
var  ps       = 360/data.length,
rng      = Math.floor((((totalNoOfObjects-picked)/totalNoOfObjects)* 360) + 1440);

rotation = (Math.round(rng / ps) * ps);

rotation += 90 - Math.round(ps/2);
vis.transition()
   .duration(3000)
   .attrTween("transform", rotTween)
   .each("end", function(){
                //populate the result
        d3.select("#result h1")
          .text(data[picked].result);
          oldrotation = rotation;
    });
```

Comment: the question is asking how to grab server response via d3.js ... I know the rotation part.